# VS2010 and Mercurial: Warning symbol on .hgignore - how to get rid of warning

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mercurial, tortoisehg

Whenever I open my VS2010 (under Mercurial) project, the `.hgignore` file is tagged with a warning. Tooltip says `Clean [default]`.

[image: hgignore warning]

Opening the file once removes the warning symbol.

[image: hgignore no warning]

Any idea, why is that and how I get rid of this warning symbol? Everything works as intended, so I have no idea what I am warned about.

Using: 2012-09-04: TortoiseHg 2.5 (with Mercurial 2.3.1) released

Comment: The symbol means that the file is included in the project but not physically present on disk. Not sure why you're getting that, as it appears not to be the case for you, but that's the usual reason you see that symbol. Now, the tooltip implies you have Visual Hg installed, so that's perhaps related? Having said all this, you don't actually need `.hgignore` included in your project.

Comment: Good hint, will exclude it and see what happens. Still unclear why I am getting the warning.